# C++ passing arguments to a program already running

Tags: c++

I'm reading through a tutorial on using voice commands to control applications and, in an example of controlling rhythmbox, it suggests commands such as the following can be executed:

```
rhythmbox-client --play
rhythmbox-client --pause
```

Why does this not simply open a new instance of the program, and how can I emulate the functionality in my own programs? For example, how could I pass a string to a particular instance of a program?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhythmbox uses inter-process communictation to achieve this type of functionality, and this can be implemented in a number of different ways. One of them is to use D-Bus, like Rhythmbox does.

Using D-Bus is not very easy, but the basic idea is that you register your application in D-Bus, so other applications can call different procedures your app exports (for example play/stop actions), and then in the same application implement a client. This way, if arguments like `--play` are passed, you don't run the usual code, but just check for an instance of the running app and send a command to your already running program.

On the other hand, when no arguments are passed, your program just starts and registers the proper triggers, so that a later called instance can control it.

Here is a [tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html) on dbus, and [the DBus homepage](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus)

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques to have only one application instance running. In these terms calling `yyy --play` would generally mean the same as

```
INSTANCE = GET_RUNNING_INSTANCE()
IF INSTANCE == NULL
   INSTANCE = CREATE_NEW_INSTANCE()
SEND_MESSAGE(INSTANCE, PLAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, how could I pass a string to a particular instance of a program?

You'll need to use whatever interprocess communication facilities your operating system offers. Sockets or named pipes, for example, or messages.